# git tag: Show only my tags?

Tags: git

Is there a way to only see my tags in git?

I have tried with `git tag --author="XXX"`, but that does not work. I could not find anything [on the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) either.

Background: This is a follow up question to: [Git: History of commits I have *checked out* since init/cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248118/git-history-list-of-commits-i-have-checked-out-since-init-cloning)

Answer (score 1):

Not really unless you signed or annotated the tag in some way. However, you might want to make 'special' tags that are not stored under `refs/tags/`. Some systems do this for transient markers for things -- gerrit is one I know of that creates 'refs/for/' and 'refs/changes/' references. You do this by creating the ref files in another directory under refs:

```
$ git update-ref refs/special/first HEAD~4
$ git update-ref refs/special/second HEAD~2
$ git tag | grep first
<nothing returned -- shows these are not tags>
$ $ git log --oneline -n 2 special/first
7c1d983 Merge branch 'pt/tcltk8513' into devel
73cdc1e Merge pull request #72 from pointoforder/devel
<it works!>
```

Also -- these do show up in gitk or `git log --decorate`. For instance:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate -n10
* 53e28dd (HEAD, origin/master, master) Installer: Continue the idea of d5f2
* 0433db0 shell prompt should not beep and only show MSYSTEM when non-standa
*   947ccf6 (refs/special/second) Merge branch 'devel' of 
|\
| * 759a59f Bash PS1: Correctly enclose nonprintable sections
| * 4e4e3f3 Bash PS1: Split up PS1 into small components
| * 707197e Bash PS1: refactor code for better readability
* | 6bf64a4 Replace 'devel' with 'master'
* |   7c1d983 (refs/special/first) Merge branch 'pt/tcltk8513' into devel
|\ \
| * | cc9382f (pt/tcltk8513) Update tk to version 8.5.13
| * | 31fbf2c Update tcl to version 8.5.13
```

So you can create some alias to make these useful to you and simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
git tag -l
git tag --list
```

should do it for all tags. But a tag is light weight so it does not store who made it.

Comment: Annotated tags are not lightweight and should have the information he's looking for, so those should store the author. OP probably doesn't know which he's using.

Comment: true. although I don't think git gives you functionality to easily filter the list of tags by the author.

Comment: No they don't. I would guess something like grep or possibly even python/perl would be better for doing that but would require actually finding the associated files for the tags.