# git hook suitable for checking changes in pull code

Tags: ruby, git, bash, githooks, git-bash

As mentioned in the question, after or at the time of pulling modified code to my production base i want to notify others about changes are going to be done to my production base or changes took place in production base through emails.

git-hooks mentioned [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) doesn't match with my criteria.

Can any one suggest me a hook/script/gem that can do my job with example?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:** Can any one give me a sample of post-merge hook

Comment: Are you sure post-merge hooks won't work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any git hook for pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185400/is-there-any-git-hook-for-pull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is duplicate of [Is there any git hook for pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185400/is-there-any-git-hook-for-pull)

For customising your request and refer this url https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717, you can prepare the hook `post-merge` as below

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

# git hook to run a command after `git pull` if a specified file was changed
# Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then put it into `.git/hooks/`.

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | mailx -s "changes found on production server!" your.mail.box@mail.com
}

# In this example it's used to send mail if there are any files changed.
check_run
```

Comment: i have less knowledge in shell scripting.
When i run with your code it tells me changed_files not found.

how to assign multiple values to a variable in shell scripting?