# Notify When Repository is Pulled

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket team with several repos.

Is there a way to get notified on my account or preferably via email when a repository is pulled?

We get notifications for pushed changes so I imagine this is possible.

I haven't been able to find anything in repo or team settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any git hook for pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185400/is-there-any-git-hook-for-pull)

Comment: I'm primarily looking for a Bitbucket setting that will send me an email when someone pulls, like we have when someone pushes changes

Answer (score -1):

You can get notification when your code was pulled.

That said, there is a `post-merge hook`, and all pulls include a merge, though not all merges are pulls.

> post-merge
>   This hook is invoked by git merge, which happens when a git pull is
>     done on a local repository.
>
> The hook takes a single parameter, a status
>     flag specifying whether or not the merge being done was a squash merge.
>
> This hook cannot affect the outcome of git merge and is not executed,
>     if the merge failed due to conflicts.
>
> This hook can be used in conjunction with a corresponding pre-commit
>     hook to save and restore any form of metadata associated with the
>     working tree (e.g.: permissions/ownership, ACLS, etc). See
>     contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that. But does your firsr sentence mean you can get notified on Bitbucket (ideally via email) when someone pulls?

Comment: yep. you should get notification on you **LOCAL** repository but not on your remote one.

Comment: Is it in bitbucket settings? It will send an email to me when someone pulls one of the team's repos?

Comment: As i said, you don't have any hook for `server-side` only for you local repo. Same as you cant be notified when someone is cloning the project. (Unless you use github which has its own webhooks configuration)