# Auto run npm install after git pull

Tags: git, npm, pm2, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

so I have my own VPS, and I installed CyberPanel to host my website. The problem is that there is no option to do a command after my git is being pulled to the server. So I have to include `node_modules` in the repository which is a pain. Is there a way to automate the `npm i` script using anything like `pm2` or something else? I have the root access in the VPS so I can install anything.

Comment: The short answer: no. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185449/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+hook