# npm run build script not working inside Git post-merge hook

Tags: git, shell, npm, githooks

I'm trying to run an npm script inside a **post-merge** *Git hook*, but the npm script isn't working. The hook is being triggered on a git pull.

Here is what my post-merge file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/jt/nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/bin/npm run build --prefix /home/jt/project/frontend
touch /home/jt/project/backend/backend/wsgi.py
```

The post-merge file is correctly located in the hooks directory within the .git directory:

```
23:44 ~/project/.git/hooks (hosting)$ tree
.
├── applypatch-msg.sample
├── commit-msg.sample
├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
├── post-merge
├── post-update.sample
├── pre-applypatch.sample
├── pre-commit.sample
├── pre-merge-commit.sample
├── pre-push.sample
├── pre-rebase.sample
├── pre-receive.sample
├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
└── update.sample
0 directories, 13 files
23:44 ~/project/.git/hooks (hosting)$
```

When I run the **npn run build** command in a shell script, it runs perfectly.

```
23:38 ~/project (hosting)$ nano test.sh
23:38 ~/project (hosting)$ ls
LICENSE  README.md  backend  frontend  test.sh
23:38 ~/project (hosting)$ source test.sh
> frontend@0.0.0 build
> vite build
vite v3.2.5 building for production...
✓ 241 modules transformed.
../backend/static/assets/react.35ef61ed.svg                   4.03 KiB
../backend/static/assets/map-pin-icon-default.2555d711.svg    0.22 KiB
../backend/static/assets/map-pin-icon-selected.0e940bf1.svg   0.23 KiB
../backend/static/assets/map-pin-icon-home.bc73a24c.svg       0.23 KiB
../backend/static/assets/bg_image.90202fe6.png                1671.34 KiB
../backend/static/index.html                                  1.00 KiB
../backend/static/assets/index.a062f1f9.css                   192.35 KiB / gzip: 27.36 KiB
../backend/static/assets/index.fd1f092a.js                    263.23 KiB / gzip: 87.69 KiB
../backend/static/assets/index.fd1f092a.js.map                1010.80 KiB
23:39 ~/project (hosting)$
```

Why is the **npm run build** script not working inside the git post-merge hook?

Answer (score 0):

First, add a `pwd; env|grep GIT` in order to validate:

- your post-merge script is actually called after a `git pull`
- from *where* it is called
- with what `GIT_DIR`/`GIT_WORKTREE` environment variable.

As in [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123053/6309), try and unset/reset `GIT_DIR`.

```bash
REPO_DIR="/path/to/your/local/repo"
cd $REPO_DIR || exit
unset GIT_DIR
...
# rest of your script
```

---

The [OP joepianoblaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11909157/joepianoblaster) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988032/npm-run-build-script-not-working-inside-git-post-merge-hook/74988197?noredirect=1#comment132376613_74988197):

> 

I added the git `post-merge` hook in my local repository in the `hooks/` folder within the `.git/` folder.
The `git pull` is being called using `GitPython` from a Django view function.

> ```py
> @api_view(['POST']) 
> def update_server(request):     
>   repo = git.Repo('/home/jt/project/.git')
>   origin = repo.remotes.origin     
>   origin.pull()     
>   return Response('Updated Python Anywhere successfully', status=200)
> ```

Comment: Would the pwd; added to the post-merge hook show up in server logs or directly on the command line?

Comment: Command-linr: it is a client side hook

Comment: I added this into the git post-merge hook but didn't see anything on the command line. I'm using GitPython to actually pull from the remote repository, so I'm thinking that could potentially be the problem.

Comment: @joepianoblaster Did you add that in your local repository? or on the server?

Comment: I added the git post-merge hook in my local repository in the hooks folder within the .git folder. The git pull is being called using GitPython from a Django view function.                                                                                    
`@api_view(['POST'])
def update_server(request):
    repo = git.Repo('/home/jt/project/.git')
    origin = repo.remotes.origin
    origin.pull()
    return Response('Updated Python Anywhere successfully', status=200)`