Git client traffic over SSH tunnel
I would like the git client to establish SSH tunnel per-repository automatically (on-demand), each time that I invoke "pull, push, ..." commands. When git client finishes processing, it should also "teardown" this SSH tunnel afterwards.
To access private git repository behind the proxy server, I'm currently doing the following :
Step 1. Configure SSH tunnel (SSH port forwarding) to proxy server (on the client side)
ssh -D 1080 -N user@proxyserver -i private_key.pem

Step 2. Configure git client, using local (per-repository) git config, to send traffic over the SSH tunnel created in Step 1.
git config --local http.sslVerify false  
git config --local http.proxy socks5h://localhost:1080

This works as expected.
Now, the question is:
Can git client be configured in such a way, so that I don't have to explicitly create an SSH tunnel each and evry time I want to access private git repository behind the proxy ?
Ideally, this "imaginary setup" should be "git authentication method" agnostic.

You can create a ssh host alias in config and configure whatever tunnel settings / jump hosts you need to configure there, and you can then juse that host alias in your checkout command for git. It's generally the same strategy as used for having multiple deploy keys: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#using-multiple-repositories-on-one-server

Thanks for the comment, I know about this one.
Unfortunately it's not "git authentication method" agnostic.

Have you take a look into git hooks? Not sure if there is a global "pre/post" hook, which fires for every command. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185449/5781499 If thats not enough, you can create a bash alias for "git" which does what you need, and pass all arguments 1:1 to the real git command.

Im turning my comment into a answer.
You can create a bash alias/function that create the SSH tunnel before executing the GIT command.

function git_with_tunnel() {

    # create ssh session & store pid
    #ssh -f -N -L local_port:remote_host:remote_port user@ssh_host
    ssh -D 1080 -N user@proxyserver -i private_key.pem
    ssh_pid=$!

    # set proxy server
    /usr/bin/git config --local http.sslVerify false
    /usr/bin/git config --local http.proxy socks5://localhost:1080

    # execute real git with all arguments
    /usr/bin/git "$@"

    # kill ssh session
    kill $ssh_pid
    
}

# "publish" alias/function
alias git='git_with_tunnel'

Have not tried it with a real ssh session, but it should work.
Add this to your ~/.bashrc file, and read/execute it contents with source ~/.bashrc to apply the made changes.
Then when you use git foo bar, it first creates the ssh session.
This is not a perfect solution.
Because it also create the tunnel for things like git --help.
Optional you can extend the function to read the first argument and establish the tunnel only when the value are only "pull, push, ..." commands

Sorry, but such "solutions" are exactly what I would like to avoid, if possible.
If it's not possible to accomplish what I described in my question without such wrappers, then I would much rather stick to my original solution.

@Observer I know no other solution if you want to do this automatically. But i dont get why you want to avoid it? Thats one of the reason why i love linux. You dont like "x"?, change it! And the solution above with a alias seems pretty straight forward.
